# Unzip compressed dump and import via psql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to dump a huge database and compress the dump in order to not have to wait hours till it's done.

I dump the database the following way:

```
 pg_dump -Fc -U -v | gzip > db$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M).tar.gz
```

This leaves me with a compressed tar file.
I know want to unzip it in order to have a .tar file only:

```
tar -xvf xxx.tar.gz
```

This leaves me with an error message saying ***This does not look like a tar archive file***

My goal is to then import it via psql.
I do not see what I am doing wrong – according to the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) on dumps, I can use -Fc to dump in any wanted format? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a tar archive, even if you named it like that, so you cannot use `tar` to unpack it.

To restore, you could use

```bash
zcat xxx.tar.gz | pg_restore -d target_database -U dbuser
```

By the way, it is pretty pointless to compress a custom format dump, since it is already compressed. You could choose better compression during `pg_dump` with the `-Z 9` option.

Comment: Thank you, how would I get a tar archive?

Comment: By using `tar` to write the dump into an archive. But why would you want a tar archive for a single file? Just compressing, like you do, is better.

Comment: I saw that people were doing it so I was wondering if that was the "best way" to dump and restore. As far as I understood, all I need is:  pg_dump -Fc -U -v | gzip > db.gz and I can later restore it with zcat/pg_restore as you explained. The reason I was trying to avoid pg_restore is because I often encountered version issues between postgres and pg_restore/pg_dump..

Comment: But these version issues are a good thing; they warn you if you are doing something wrong. With a plain format dump, you'll just run into an error.